# Cache misses for lazy loaded resources (using dynamic imports)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

In a Vue.js project created with Vue CLI (internally using webpack), I implement code splitting and lazy loading with dynamic imports like so:

```js
import(/* webpackChunkName: "my-feature" */ "./my-feature.js");
```

As a result I get the expected set of files:

1. dist/myApp.umd.min.js
2. dist/myApp.umd.min.vendors~my-feature.js (my-feature dependencies)
3. dist/myApp.umd.min.my-feature.js

The Vue application is built as a library and then used for an existing web site. What I do is include `myApp.umd.min.js` in <head> (common to all pages), and then in <body> request code I need for that page (for example `myApp.umd.min.my-feature.js`). Dependencies (`myApp.umd.min.vendors~my-feature.js`) are automatically requested by the earlier script.

---

**Problem**

When I navigate to a page, that uses the Vue app (and specifically my-feature), all 3 of the above files are loaded. That is expected for the first visit, but if I move to a different page and then return, only the first file (`myApp.umd.min.js`) is loaded from cache. The other ones are loaded from server every time I visit the page.

What approach to take for the lazy-loaded scripts to come from cache once already loaded? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So far I have not found anything better than including all the scripts, I need on the page, in its `<head>` section. Moreover only using `<script>` tag helped; `<link href="..." rel="preload" as="script">` was useless.

Answer (score 0):

Use a version parameter for the script url.

There's a code snippet that showcase this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myApp.umd.min.js?v=123"></script>
```

Also this is a valid solution:

```
<link rel="preload" href="myFont.woff2" as="font"
      type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

From docs:

A `rel` value of preload indicates that the browser should preload this resource with the as attribute indicating the specific class of content being fetched. The crossorigin attribute indicates whether the resource should be fetched with a CORS request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Directly referencing each file with `<script>` does help (even without version specification), but it is a pity I have to do this manually. With webpack I can only reference the top of the tree and then it pulls everything it needs. However caching doesn't work then.
I've tried `<link rel="preload" as="script">`, but that didn't work either - when webpack inserts `<script>` for dependencies the resources are loaded again despite the preload link.